# Web worker onMessage receives message twice

Tags: javascript, angular, web-worker

When I issue webworker.postMessage('any message'), it gets processed twice by the onMessage listener. I tried running stopPropagation on the message, but it still gets run again. I verified by console.log that the call to postMessage in the main thread only gets called once. I verified that the webworker being called is unique. Can I fix it so that it postMessage only results in *one* onMessage event being called?

Snippet showing call to web worker:

```
        this.webworker.postMessage('Message one');
    }
```

My web worker:

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

onmessage = function(data) {
    console.log('@@ in web worker' + JSON.stringify(data.data));
    data.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE], with just enough to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened also to me. I can't explain why, even I did some test. Anyway my only contribute is that the same somewhat buggy script gave me the doubled console.log message only in Firefox, not in Edge, nor Chrome.

Anyhow in my simple test worker I set a counter. This way I can confirm that the execution happens only once, and the issue is only related to the console.log.

```
    self.curcounter=self.curcounter+ 1; //this has been executed once
    self.console.log('WORKER received a INT:' + e.data + ' self.curcounter: '+ self.curcounter); //this twice
```

Comment: Got the same problem when posting a single message from a react component to WebWorker. I can log two onmessage events in the worker and two received messages in the react component. Using FF DevEd 97.0b8.
Opera  83.0.4254.19 on the other hand doesn't log twice but anyway receives two events back.

Comment: Seems to happen only in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

As of firefox 121, what worked for me was

> self.onmessage = function(event) {
> if(event.data && !event.data.devtoolsEnabled ) {

At least on my machine, this seems to be a side effect of the Vue.js devtools extension (currently v6.5.1)